ROS 2 Humble Nodes and Topics Don't Show Up in Docker with QEMU on Jetson Orin
I’m running into an issue with ROS 2 Humble nodes and topics not appearing in a Docker container.
Here’s my setup:

Device: Jetson Orin AGX 64GB (arm64)
Docker image: ros:humble (amd64)
Using qemu-user-static for amd64    emulation on arm64

Reason for this setup: I need to use a .so library that’s only available for amd64, and the vendor hasn’t provided an arm64 version.
The problem:
When I run a ROS 2 node inside the container, I can’t see its topics using ros2 topic list in another terminal (even within the same container). Similarly, the node doesn’t show up with ros2 node list. Even if I use ros2 topic pub to publish a topic from one terminal, it doesn’t show up in another terminal within the container.
Here’s how I run the Docker container:
docker run -it --privileged --platform linux/amd64 \
  -e ROS_DOMAIN_ID=6 \
  -v /home/test_ws:/home/test_ws \
  -w /home/test_ws \
  ros:humble

Am I missing any configuration or setup steps to make ROS 2 work properly in this environment?
Thanks!
